# 4506-T a month after closing?

Tags: united-states, taxes, mortgage

A month ago I closed on a typical 30 Year Mortgage for a second home. Why would my title company ask for a signed 4506-T a month after closing?

Comment: Title company, not mortgage lender?

Comment: Correct. But, maybe it's on the mortgage company's behalf? They are blaming the notary, claiming the notary skipped it by accident. But, from what I understand of that form, it seems like something that would have been requested during qualifying? Not a form you sign at a closing? I guess I don't understand why you'd need the form at all after or during signing unless they suspected mortgage fraud post-signing.

Comment: It's possible it is due to an audit on their side (perhaps likely even) - the form must exist for them to meet Fannie Mae's rules.

Comment: That makes sense - I'll bet you're right. I wonder what happens if I just ignore their requests and refuse to sign it? lol

I really hated that mortgage company. I've done this 8 times now and that was the worst!

Comment: You likely have a clause in your mortgage instructing you to comply with reasonable requests for documentation after the fact if they miss something.  Realistically you mostly would irritate someone who's just doing their job (perhaps not as well as they ought).

Comment: I guess I'll be nice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is a bit odd the title company is asking (and not the lender), it's probable that they audited the paperwork and found it missing.  A 4506-T is often a requirement for loans to comply with Fannie Mae/Freddie Mac rules, meaning they can be sold to these major purchasers of mortgages only with the required form.

If I were you, I would sign and return the form, as long as you're sure you're talking to your title agent or the lender and not being scammed by some third party phishing you.  It is something you typically would have done during the mortgage process, so it's not out of the norm.  Your mortgage likely includes language requiring you to comply with reasonable requests like this, and even if it doesn't, if you don't you're just going to irritate someone who's just doing their job by refusing and gaining no particular benefit to yourself (assuming you were forthright with your income declarations).

Comment: Regarding your parenthetical at the end, I wonder how it might play out if they got your tax return and discovered you were not forthright about your income. At that point what recourse do they have? The money is already spent...

Comment: @TTT Lawsuit for fraud?

Comment: Apparently a mortgage company can call the note due at anytime if they discover you lied on the application. http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/what-is-mortgage-loan-fraud.html